# XAML browser window control

Tags: c#, xaml

We are running a Windows application built with XAML and C#.

We are using the web browser control as part of our application in which we are feeding a webpage into it controlled controlled in our CMS so we can control the content of the webpage.

I did an alert to see what version the built in browser was for our XAML project.  The browser ended up being MSIE 7.  BIG NO NO.  We want to be able to use some more modern web languages like HTML 5 that feeds the page.

Is there a way to update the browser window IE version or a way to tell the browser window control to use Chrome or other browser instead of the default one?

Thanks.

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember in WinForms, the `WebBrowser` version was the same as the version of IE installed on that machine, I'm assuming it's still the same in WPF. And no, you can't change the default control to use Chrome. There is however, a [.NET implementation of Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) which according to its documentation supports HTML5 as well.

Comment: This seems to not be the case. On my machine I have IE9. I did an JS alert on the browser and it gave me version MSIE 7.0.  Hmm. I will look into the Chromium. But if anyone else has any suggestions.

Comment: @Carlos How are you determining what version the control is using? Navigate to http://www.whatismybrowser.com/ with the control and see what it says.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Well originally I was using Javascript/jQuery to detect the browser and version.  This seemed to steer me wrong.  According to whatismybrowser.com it is showing IE9.  So that being said.  HTML5 is going to work on a Windows 8 machine running our app because it has IE10.  Thanks for the info.